# Smooth curve on $TM$

Tags: smooth-manifolds, coordinate-systems, curves, tangent-bundle

I have to solve this one:

> "Given a smooth curve $\gamma$ on a smooth manifold $M$, prove that $\gamma'$ is a smooth curve on the tangent bundle $TM$".

I have this idea:

let $(U,\varphi)$ a local chart on $M$ with local coordinates $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. If $\gamma(t_0)\in U$ then for $t$ close enough to $t_0$ we have $\gamma(t)=(\gamma_1(t),\ldots,\gamma_n(t))$ where $\gamma_i=x^i\circ\gamma$.

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rcl}
 & \gamma & \\
\mathbb{R} &\longrightarrow & M \\
\gamma' & \searrow & \uparrow\pi \\
 & & TM
\end{array}
\end{equation}
So
\begin{eqnarray*}
\gamma'(t_0)&=&\left(\gamma(t_0),\gamma_{*t_0}\left(\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=t_0}\right)\right)\\
&=&\left(\gamma(t_0),\sum_{i=1}^n\gamma'_i(t_0)\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right|_{t=t_0}\right)\\
&=&\left( \gamma_1(t_0),\ldots,\gamma_n(t_0),\gamma'_1(t_0),\ldots,\gamma'_n(t_0) \right)
\end{eqnarray*}
is a smooth curve on $TM$.

Is it all right?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This seems correct.